# Matlab: descritize column values to range 0 - 40

Tags: matlab, matrix

In case I have a matrix M, how can I discretize values of specific columns  to range 0 - 40 ?

Comment: If you have Matlab >= 2015a, you may find [`discretize`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) function useful

Comment: This question is not clear. Please give an example of the inputs of `M` and an example of the discretized outputs that you are looking for.